# Preact with rollup plugin alias

Tags: rollupjs, preact

```
alias({
    "react": path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/preact/dist/preact.js'),
    "react-dom": path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/preact-compat/dist/preact-compat.js'),
}),

import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {

}
```

**Throws: *'Component' is not exported by node_modules\preact\dist\preact.js***

But this works

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {

}
```